# Dynamically set cell values from table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I've got an excel document that essentially looks like this (imagine it having around 15 000 rows):

```
A    B    C    D    E    F
---------------------------
Art  Price    Art  Price
---------------------------
A    1         A    5
A    3         B    10
A    4         C    8
B    7         
B    2
C    3
C    15
```

As you can see the prices in column B are inconsistent.

What I want to do is to set the prices (in column B) to the correct prices (that are found in column E) based on the articles name (found in column A and D).

Unfortunately I'm at loss when it comes to VBA in Excel, and formulas in Excel, what would be a smart way to approach (or solve) this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `VLOOKUP` excel formula in the excel help, no coding needed.

Enter `=VLOOKUP(A2;$D$2:$E$4;2)` in cell `B2` and fill down.

Comment: That would be a nice solution, but would require some time since there are around 300 different articles and 15000+ rows.

Comment: No, just enter the formula in the top cell (`B2` in your example above), select the entire range by clicking **CTRL** + **SHIFT** + **Arrow down**, and press **CTRL** + **D** to copy down.